# Shows "#" instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle11g

I am executing this code:

```
  def find_all_from_id
     Note.find_by_sql([%{SELECT NOTE_N FROM NOTES WHERE ORDSP_ID = #{@order.order_number}}])
   end
```

And in ERB file, I have an output:

```
<div class="form-field notes-div" >
    <%= service_form.label :notes, "Pakalpojuma papildinformācija:", :class => "label_for_cod", :style=>"width: 170px;" %>
    <div style="float:left; width:400px;"><%#= notes %> <%= find_all_from_id %></div>
</div>
```

It puts the `#` symbol instead of text the that comes from the database (http://prntscr.com/kop3mz). Why? And how can I fix that?

Comment: Please include code snippets rather than images of code

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Done.

Comment: is `find_all_from_id` returning an integer or a a Note instance?

Comment: You really want to use placeholder values here, not [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). For example: `find_all_by_sql([ 'SELECT NOTE_N FROM NOTES WHERE ORDSP_ID=?', @order.order_number ])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `find_by_sql`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html

This method will return an array of instances.  If you want to display information about those instances you need to iterate through the array and manually display the information you want to show. Erb will not display the array of instances, leading to your issue.

E.g.

```
<% find_all_from_id.each do |note| %> 
    <%= note.name %> 
    <%= note.id %> 
<% end %>
```